# serving video ads along with video contents in android

Tags: android, video, admob

My android app has video contents that my users can watch. I would like to include video ads along with the content: similar to how everyone is doing it, such as youtube or TV network websites like `nbc.com`, etc.

If you ever watch Youtube videos or TV on your computer, the ads are interspersed in the content: before, after, or in between. That's what I want. Will someone provide some pointers or an example on how to do this with an ads provider such as AdMob? And no, my contents are not Youtube contents.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want AdMob so much as you want the [Interactive Media Ads SDK](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/?hl=en). It can do prerolls, postrolls, non-linear ads, and so on.

Comment: I up voted your answer before asking my question :). There is a thing about not using ads during development, how do I test this video add system during development?

Comment: Test tags! https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/tags?hl=en